# SharePoint main page calendar view sorting

Tags: sorting, view, calendar, settings, sharepoint-online

How to sort calendar view on SharePoint main page in descending order (latest dates on top). Already in list view I have done but not appearing on main Page.[Main page calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4meYy.png)

I have done in event list view and sorted in descending order and while I am replicating on main page there is no option to sort. [Options while adding Calendar on main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Y1W.png)

I tried viewing some options are available in SharePoint design but not able to make it?

Can anyone help to sort out this

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge，if you create a calendar view in the list, you can sort by dates, but the web part in the page has no OOTB way to sort by dates.